# How to convert column into row

Tags: excel

I hv this format in excel (column):-

[image]

I wish to convert it into row:-

[image]

Is it possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: Its possible .. Have u tried to code ?

Comment: Code ? You mean VBA ? I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Unpivot if you are using excel 2013

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot (eg as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-flatten)), drill down on the intersection of the two Grand Totals and move cells with blanks in ColumnB but values in third up to row two. Delete rows with blanks in ColumD. Change labels to suit.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple with offsets:

Following your image you may write:

- In cell B7: `=$A$3`
- In cell C7: `=OFFSET($A$3,0,(ROW(A7)-7)*2+1)`
- In cell D7: `=OFFSET($A$3,0,(ROW(A7)-6)*2)`

Then fill rows as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can also unpivot using [my unpivot add-in](http://tduhameau.wordpress.com/2012/09/24/the-unpivot-add-in/), after unmerging the top cells. You can use the below code to unmerge your top row first:

```
Sub UnmergeTopRow()

Dim lLastcol As Long, lcolLoop As Long

lLastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column

Range("B1", Cells(1, lLastcol)).UnMerge

With Range("B1", Cells(1, lLastcol))
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
    .Value = .Value
End With

End Sub
```